# Tobi example in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, action

I am trying to reproduce Tobi test example from the book "Node.js" in Action" the first edition from chapter 10.

I created two files forms.js containing REST api and rendering to-do submit form and first.js. defining Tobi test logic. I launch HTTP server from form.js. When I fire a test in first.js adding to-do task an error happens.

```
(node:13137) [DEP0025] DeprecationWarning: sys is deprecated. Use util instead.
Here code is:

/home/taras/tobiframework/node_modules/tobi/lib/browser.js:93
  this.window = jsdom.jsdom(wrap(html), null, options).createWindow();
                      ^

TypeError: jsdom.jsdom is not a function
    at Browser.parse (/home/taras/tobiframework/node_modules/tobi/lib/browser.js:93:23)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/taras/tobiframework/node_modules/tobi/lib/browser.js:280:14)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:202:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
```

I expect the output without errors or it is deprecated?

Comment: What is a Tobi test?  Is it relevant to this question?

Comment: Are you refererring to this https://www.npmjs.com/package/tobi? The package `jsdom` has had some changes to its API which is why this example is failing. I would not recommend trying to follow along with a 8 year old book anyways.